# Anaconda installation problem in Windows 10 64-bit

Tags: python, windows, installation, anaconda

Before I installed Anaconda in my computer before but accidentally uninstalled it. As I tried to re-download and re-install it, I found a problem. Although the system shows installation is complete, the entire Anaconda3 folder is only 700M+ in size, which is much smaller than normal. Also, I cannot find anaconda in start menu. What should I do to correctly re-install this software? I have tried this for several days.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The info you provided is not enough for others to help you. Please provide a more detailed description. Could you find "Anaconda Prompt" from startup menu. What is the absolute path referred by you as "Anaconda3 folder"? What's the value of you environment variable `PATH`? What installation options are checked by you from [this menu](https://docs.anaconda.com/_images/win-install-options.png)?

Comment: No, I cannot find anything, including navigator and anaconda prompt. The folder is C:\Users\katie\Anaconda3, and I cannot find any executables in that folder (except for uninstall file).
The option I chose is what the system recommends me: only me, not add to the path.